# Is there a non-reflexive Banach space with every proper closed subspace reflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Many conditions necessary for reflexivity of a Banach space turn out to be sufficient as well, for example, compactness of the closed unit ball in the weak topology. I am wondering if there is any sort of converse to the fact that every closed subspace of a Banach space is reflexive.

Namely, let $X$ be a Banach space such that every proper closed subspace of $X$ is reflexive. Does this imply that $X$ itself is reflexive?

Comment: No there is no such example as in the title. Yes, to your last question: Every non-zero continuous linear functional gives you a decomposition $X \cong Y \oplus \mathbb{R}$ with $Y = \operatorname{Ker}\varphi$ reflexive by hypothesis. Direct sums of reflexive spaces are reflexive and reflexivity is preserved under isomorphism of Banach spaces.

Comment: @t.b.: of course you require the Axiom of Choice for that!

Comment: @Davide: well, that's also nice, but it makes me think of sparrows and cannons... :)

Comment: @GEdgar: yes, I do. I can live with that...

Comment: Allowing hyperplanes makes it too easy.  What about if we just require that every closed subspace of infinite codimension is reflexive?

Comment: @Robert: According to [an exercise in Bourbaki](http://books.google.com/books?id=sbgM1HD_ticC&pg=SL265-PA69) (TVS I, Ch. IV §5, Exer. 12, p. IV.69) every non-reflexive Banach space contains a non-reflexive subspace of infinite codimension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making my comments into an answer: No there are no such Banach spaces.

Assume that every proper subspace of $X$ is reflexive. Take a non-zero continuous linear functional $\varphi: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $Y = \operatorname{Ker}{\varphi}$ and choose $x_0 \in X$ with $\varphi(x_0) = 1$. By continuity of $\varphi$ the space $Y$ is a closed subspace. The map $Y \oplus \mathbb{R} \to X$ given by $(y,t) \mapsto y + t x_0$ is continuous with continuous inverse $x \mapsto (x - \varphi(x)\cdot x_0,\, \varphi(x))$, hence $X \cong Y \oplus \mathbb{R}$. By hypothesis $Y$ is reflexive, hence so is $Y \oplus \mathbb{R}$ and thus $X$ is reflexive, too. Replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$ gives the same for complex Banach spaces.

---

Weakening the hypotheses as Robert suggested makes it a bit more subtle, but still manageable:

> Every non-reflexive Banach space contains a non-reflexive closed subspace of infinite codimension.
>
> (Bourbaki, *[Topological vector spaces 1](http://books.google.com/books?id=sbgM1HD_ticC)*, Exercise 12 to Chapter IV, §5, page IV.69.)

Passing to the contrapositive, if every closed subspace of infinite codimension is reflexive, then $X$ must be reflexive.

The following is a slightly expanded version of the hint given by Bourbaki:

By the [Eberlein–Šmulian theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein-Smulian_theorem), a non-reflexive Banach space $X$ contains a bounded sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ without weak accumulation point. Note that this implies that the $x_n$ must span an infinite-dimensional subspace of $X$. Using the [Riesz-lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) on almost orthogonal vectors to closed subspaces, it is not difficult to extract a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and a topologically independent sequence $(y_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\|x_{n_k} - y_{k}\| \leq \frac{1}{k}$ [topologically independent means that no $y_k$ is in the closed linear span of $\{y_n\}_{n \neq k}$ ]. This yields that every weak accumulation point of the $y_k$ is also a weak accumulation point of the $x_n$. The closed subspace $Y$ generated by the $\{y_{2k}\}$ is thus a non-reflexive subspace of $X$ (by Eberlein–Šmulian again) and it has infinite codimension by construction.